# Github cant read csv data

Tags: excel, csv, github, jekyll, data-files

I uploaded my jekyll site to github, and created a table for my data files.

The data is showing when I run the website locally.
Unfortunately, After I upload it to github, I doesnt show anymore.

I have my csv data named "`vclists.csv`" under "_csv" folder.

Heres my repository - https://github.com/geloangelia/myvcsite/

Heres the link where the table of my data files should show.

https://geloangelia.github.io/myvcsite/jekyll/update/2017/01/20/welcome-to-jekyll.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most of the time that Github pages fails to generate a site, there is an inconsistency in `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

You need to run `bundle update` to rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only the gems in your `Gemfile`, and commit the `Gemfile.lock`.

Also, the data being loaded isn't the one located at `_csv` folder, is the one in the `_data` folder.

Comment: I created a table of data files an follow this steps that why I have "_csv" folder. See link = https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-csv_read

Comment: I won't use a 3 year old plugin.. What you see is the first tag `{{ site.data.vclist }}`, it load the data from the `_data` folder, the other content isn't being generated

Comment: Do you have any recommendation so I can make a table from my csv data files?

Comment: process each row like a common data file, adjust the tags to create a table `<ul>
{% for item in site.data.vclist %}
  <li>{{item.No}}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>`